# Send POST request to another action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

That's just an example to know how to send a POST request from the action. So, let's say I have an action:

```
def download
  @t = params[:url]
end
```

I want to send a POST request to another action, let's call it `doStuffWithPost`:

```
def doStuffWithPost
  # Save a row with that POST info, url_column = POST['url']
end

def download
  @t = params[:url]
  # Send POST with POST['url'] = @t
end
```

In PHP I would use CURL probably, which requires quite lots of code. Is there an easy way to do that in Rails? If not, what should I use to pass parameters from one action and call the another? Thanks.

Comment: First of all what you are trying to is a bad practice.  I wouldnt recommend you to do what you are trying to do.Inter-controller communication in a Rails app (or any web app following the same model-adapter-view pattern for that matter) is something you should actively avoid. When you are tempted to do so consider it a sign that you are fighting the patterns and framework your app is built on and that you are relying on logic has been implemented at the wrong layer of your application.

Comment: This is not what controller actions are for.

Comment: @zeantsoi What should I use instead?

Comment: This is fr cronjob by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to post to another action here, just follow the rails pattern (if you've ever scaffolded a new resource, you should have seen this before):

```
def download
  url = Url.new(params[:url])
  if url.save
    redirect_to happy_route
  else
    redirect_to unhappy_route
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [httpparty gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to do this. Here a post method [example](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/basic.rb)
But, like the other guys said, don't use this if you don't have a good reason. You can use this if you need to talk with an api for example...